# Is there a REST equivalent API to Air/Fulfill in Sabre?

Tags: php, rest, soap, air, sabre

As I'm working with PHP REST API's are prefered, someone know if Sabre have REST equivalent to SOAP APIs listed bellow, or do I have other way to work catching my Sales?
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/fulfill/Get_Sales_Reports
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/fulfill/Get_eTicket_Details

I am trying to capture our Sales directly from Sabre to bill Passagers, if you know other way that I capture this, I'm listening!

Answer (score 0):

No, they only have these available as SOAP APIs. I'm afraid there is no REST equivalent.